# Get the Key Value Pairs from a nested Hash when given a Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hashmap

I have a nested hash `pdf_hash` that has three common keys `:x`, `:y` and `:text`.
I know the value of the key `:text`. Now I have to look through each page of the PDF and get the key-value pairs of `:x` and `:y` for the given `:text => value`.

This is my current code:

```
def deep_find(pdf_hash, value, found=nil)
  if pdf_hash.respond_to?(:value?) && pdf_hash.value?(value)
    return pdf_hash[:x] && pdf_hash[:y]
    puts pdf_hash[:x] && pdf_hash[:y]
  elsif pdf_hash.is_a? Enumerable
    pdf_hash.find {|*a| found = deep_find(a.last, value) }
    return found
  end
end

deep_find(coordinates, "YOUR DUE DATE CHANGE REQUEST")
```

But it is not printing any result.

I also tried 
value = "YOUR DUE DATE CHANGE REQUEST"

```
texts = coordinates.map do|page|
 page[:lines].find {|a| a[:text] == value}
 puts "#{:x} && #{:y}"
end
```

This is  printing 
x && y every time it is finding the given value.
But I need the values of x and y also.
How do I print the key and value ?

Comment: I don't understand why you have a question mark in this: `(:value?)`

Comment: @JohnMessenger Because they are testing if `pdf_hash` responds to a method named `value?` (which is called on the same line).

Comment: comparing the given value with the value in the Hash

Answer (score 0):

It's not printing anything because you have `puts` on the line *after* `return`. No code in a method is executed after a `return` has been reached.

Comment: I also tried to print on the same line as Returns. but it is giving syntax error. Where do I print then ?

Comment: I can't diagnose a syntax error without seeing the code. You should print before the `return` or you should print the value returned by the method (i.e. put `puts` outside your method, not inside it).

Comment: I did this  puts deep_find(coordinates, "YOUR DUE DATE CHANGE REQUEST") but no change.

Comment: It's not clear why you're printing anything within this method. Are you just printing for debugging purposes? Otherwise you should just print the result returned by the method, outside of the method. You can't just replace `return` with `puts`, as `puts` returns `nil`.

Comment: I need to print the result returned by the method. I tried value = "YOUR DUE DATE CHANGE REQUEST"
  texts = coordinates.map do|page|
    page[:lines].find {|a| a[:text] == value}
    puts "#{:x} && #{:y}"
  end  But it is printing the keys but not  the values x && y. I need the Key and the Value of the hash.

Comment: If you need to print the result returned by the method, then put your `puts` outside of the method. If you've tried that and your method isn't returning the right value, then that's a different problem and you should post a new question. I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you do.